# Shortest path to visit all nodes

Tags: java, algorithms, algorithm-analysis, genetic-algorithms, graph-traversal

I am given a set of tourist attractions(nodes identified by x, y) and i need to find the shortest path to visit them.

The way i thought of it, is i will ignore if there are streets available and consider the streets always go the way a segment uniting the two points does. However, i need to find the shortest path through them; is this a correct approach to solving this problem?

From what i have read, i should apply the Traveling Salesman Problem or the Chinese Postman Problem, but i cannot figure out which one is more suitable for my case?

Also, if i am to apply TSP, is it better to go at it with a dynamic approach or a genetic algorithm one? Can you please provide an efficient implementation, if possible, as i have found only few resources and i am uneasy as to their efficiency.

Comment: The point of someone pointing out the Traveling Salesman Problem is to point out that there **is** no efficient, general purpose solution to your problem. The best you can get is a somewhat efficient _short_ path which might be the shortest (or an exceptionally slow shortest path via brute force - unless your graph is too big, in which case it is too slow to finish in your lifetime).

Comment: i will have less than 50 nodes, i think, but i would like this to be as efficient as possible...so, TSP is the way to go at this, and you are suggesting brute force instead of a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Even 50 nodes is probably too much to brute force.

Comment: Does your task have a requirement to not visit vertices and edges more then once ? If no, you can look at minimal spanning tree for the graph.

Comment: This is not like Travelling Purchaser, as it differs in purpose, i just need to traverse all the tourist attractions in the least amount of time, i can go back from one to the other if that will help, as long as i see them all in as little time as possible. Each edge comes at a cost(the time it takes from source to destination node), therefore i must ensure i choose the best way from the source node to the rest. Is the minimal spanning tree faster than the TSP? I have been searching for a proper implementation, and an explanation about their complexity, but i didn't find anything certain

Comment: @SummerCode it is [still equivalent to the TSP](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6316). The route A-B-A-C could be considered to be the route A-B-(AC) where the cost to go to C backtracking through A from B exists with a given cost. Thus, the issue of the exact solution to a TSP variation is still answered by the duplicate that Jim G. found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't present an efficient algorithm.

- You may have a look at zero-supressed decision diagrams (ZSDD / ZDD) to enumerate all paths and represent every path in a compact form.
- [Zero-Suppressed BDDs for Set Manipulation in Combinatorial Problems by Shin-ichi Minato (NTT LSI Laboratories)](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~xydong/files/proceedings/DAC2011/data/1964-2006_papers/PAPERS/1993/DAC93_272.PDF)
- since you now have a compact representation you can search for the minimal solution more efficient.
- You may have a look Donald Ervin Knuth's book 'The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 4.a' Chapter 7.1.4 which focusses on this topic.